# Text area spell Checking pop up not displaying?

Tags: css

In my site there is a text area, where i want to be spell check. But this text area only display wrong word but not appear a popup for right words.
what i can do.

" Actually there is flash work on the site also. and banner to each side of the content, and that text area is in the center.. so why the pop up not displaying..?????? 
"

Can anyone notice this type of problem, where textarea self spell-checking popup not appear..????

Comment: Where is your textarea? What spell checking solution are you using? I can't see any code or links, I don't know how to answer this question!

Comment: it is on the local.. i meant that the default spell checking is not working i.e no popup display for options...

Comment: We need more information, do you mean the browsers spellchecking?

Comment: Basically i want another one to highlight words, but the default browsers spellchecking is also not working. no popup appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i find, the answer why not appear the pop-up on textarea. Because on my site i restrict the user not to copy any content of page.. when i disable that js. then its working..

Now i will find another solution for it but the main problem is solved.!